# Showing only certain amount of users

Tags: php, html, wordpress

On my site I am showing all users with their profile picture that have subscribed to the site (using Wordpress/PHP). I am struggling to only show 20 random that have signed up tho, could anyone please advise?

My code is as follows:-

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'subscriber',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
    );
    $users = get_users( $args );

    echo '<ul class="user-list">';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {echo '<li>' . get_avatar( $user->user_email , 96 ) . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you using any framework/CMS? It looks like you're using Wordpress, which you should mention. Otherwise, we have no idea how your site works.

Comment: Yes correct we are using wordpress, il add that now!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you're not attempting to show the users in random order, rather trying to get 20 random users to show. If that's the case, you likely have to run two queries.

First, you would need to get all the IDs for the Subscriber role. Then create an array of random IDs from that initial returned array from the first query. Something like this:

**First part: Get the Subscriber IDs and create an array of 20 random IDs**

```
<?php

// First query includes grabbing all IDs from Subscriber role

$args = array(
  'role' => 'subscriber',
  'fields' => 'ID' // Use the fields param since all we need to return right now is IDs
);

$user_ids = get_users( $args ); // This will return an array of user IDs

$random_ids = array_rand( $user_ids, 20 ); // We'll create a new array of 20 random user IDs
```

**Second part: Run another query for user data, using the random IDs we just generated**

```
// Create a new query to get data for the 20 random IDs 
// Note that the role param is removed since we already queried that

$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'include' => $random_ids // Only get data for the IDs that are in our array or random user IDs
);

// Get your data and output it

$random_users = get_users( $args ); ?>
```

**Third part: Output your data how you want**

```
<ul class="user-list">

<?php 

foreach ($random_users as $user) { ?>

  <li><?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, 96); ?></li>
  
<?php } ?>

</ul>
```

**Here it is all together**

```
<?php

// First query includes grabbing all IDs from Subscriber role

$args = array(
  'role' => 'subscriber',
  'fields' => 'ID'
);

$user_ids = get_users( $args ); // This will return an array of user IDs

$random_ids = array_rand( $user_ids, 20 ); // We'll create a new array of 20 random user IDs 

// Create a new query to get data for the 20 random IDs 

$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'include' => $random_ids
);

// Get your data and output it

$random_users = get_users( $args ); ?>

<ul class="user-list">

<?php 

foreach ($random_users as $user) { ?>

  <li><?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, 96); ?></li>
  
<?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @dubvader, thanks for the above but unfortunitely this isn't showing the users. Any ideas why this could be? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding 'echo' prior to the ```get_avatar()``` function. I've updated the above.